# Appearance of 'play' button

Tags: android, button, media-player

I'm playing an audio file using the `MediaPlayer` class. At the moment I start the playback by pressing a normal button (that displays 'Play') that I created in the layout file. I want to know if it's possible to change the appearance of the button to the default android play/pause/stop buttons, without using `imagebutton`. I only want the one button, so I also don't want to use `MediaController` either. Can the default play/pause/stop buttons for android be accessed somehow?
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find list of default drawables of android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

and i think, what you need is ic_media_play, ic_media_pause.

you can access them using resource id : android.ic_media_play

here is another old link you can follow: http://www.darshancomputing.com/android/1.5-drawables.html